# 'NoneType' object has no attribute, reference class variable declared before __init__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-requests

I am using Flask with SQLAlchemy to create a 1-to-1 relationship between a Search request and parsed Data. Once a user has checked over the search results, they can click continue to parse the data (and create a Data class instance). However, I am unsure how to reference class variables before an `__init__` reference. I want my `Data` instance to have a requests response object `r`.

Calling code (views.py):

```
search = Search(form)  # create source result
search.author = g.user
db.session.add(search)
db.session.commit()

...

data = Data()
data.search_id = this_search.id
db.session.add(data)
db.session.commit()
```

Search class (models.py):

```
class Search(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    data_id = db.relationship('Data', backref='source', lazy='dynamic')
    ...
```

Data class (models.py):

```
class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    search_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('search.id'))
    search = db.relationship('Search', backref="information")
    r = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.r = requests.get(self.search.url)
```

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'

It is clear that I cannot create `self.r` before the `Data.search` variable is declared, since the error suggests that it is `NoneType` type. I am not sure what the proper format creating new variables like this should be. The code works if I move the `self.r` declaration to a class method that is called after initialization. Thanks!

Comment: I would put your initializer functions INTO the `__init__`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few recommendations

The `search` attributes actually *is* declared, it's just not set.  If it wasn't declared, you would get an `AttributeError`.

Call the superclass `__init__`.  This is just good practice for all classes

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    super(Data, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could compute the value lazily

```
class Data(...):
    ...
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self._r = None

    @property
    def r(self):
        if self._r is None and self.search is not None:
            self._r = requests.get(self.search.url)
        return self._r
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I have been reading into the way Python structures @properties, but I am still a bit confiused. So if I wanted to break the property up into a getter and a setter, it seems as though setting `r` via `self.r(self.search.url)`, I get the error `NoneType object is not callable`. Even if I don't break it up, how would I set `r`?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now! I don't need to explicitly call anything to set `r` based on your suggestion. Now I can access `r` via `data.r`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If you wanted to expose the ability to set `r`, you can decorate another method with `@r.setter` and have the method accept a single argument, then you can set that value to `self._r` or whatever else you want to do with it.